# how to highlight cells over 48 hours

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight cells in a range which are older then 48 hours. The code I have at the moment is below and highlights the cells but when I try to unhighlight the cells that are not over 48hours, they stay highlighted.
I am new to VBA code and this as boggled me after reading numerous pages. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To cell.Rows.Count
    If cell.Cells(i, 1).Value > Date - 48 Then
        cell.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone
        If cell.Cells(i, 1).Value < Date - 48 Then
            cell.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Thanks

Comment: `Date - 2` is two days (48 hours) ago.  And `cell.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` should work to remove any fill

Comment: Ah brilliant. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you want it to go red if the value is more than 48 hours ago, or 2 days? If the cells contain the time, then I assume 48 hours is the requirement so you'll need to compare it with `Now` rather than `Date`. Try this:

```
For i = 1 To cell.Rows.Count
    With cell.Cells(i, 1)
        If .Value > Now - 2 Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Else
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Or slightly tidier:

```
For Each leftmostcell In cell.Columns(1).Cells
    If leftmostcell.Value > Now - 2 Then
        leftmostcell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Else
        leftmostcell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
```

Personally, I wouldn't call my range 'cell' as it's very confusing to look at. You might want to consider renaming it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually wanted to delete the row, which I figured out and have now completed the code.

Comment: No problem. Choose one of the responses as an answer or create an answer yourself and mark that if it better answers your question.